# Why is Windows DSC LCM running every 5 hours

Tags: windows, powershell, dsc

I have two servers running Windows DSC that should both be running every 15 min but one is running correctly and the other is running ever 5 hours for some reason yet to be discovered. Here are the two LCM configurations:

The one that works:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-DSCLocalConfigurationManager

ActionAfterReboot              : ContinueConfiguration
AgentId                        : 420E62A0-FE64-11F5-9732-003ADC065DC3
AllowModuleOverWrite           : False
CertificateID                  :
ConfigurationDownloadManagers  : {}
ConfigurationID                : 82xx1e91-4bz8-4fe4-b8dc-o73bc77c8756
ConfigurationMode              : ApplyAndAutoCorrect
ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins : 15
Credential                     :
DebugMode                      : {NONE}
DownloadManagerCustomData      : {MSFT_KeyValuePair (key = "ServerUrl"), MSFT_KeyValuePair (key =
                                 "AllowUnsecureConnection")}
DownloadManagerName            : WebDownloadManager
LCMCompatibleVersions          : {1.0, 2.0}
LCMState                       : Idle
LCMStateDetail                 :
LCMVersion                     : 2.0
StatusRetentionTimeInDays      : 10
PartialConfigurations          :
RebootNodeIfNeeded             : False
RefreshFrequencyMins           : 30
RefreshMode                    : Pull
ReportManagers                 : {}
ResourceModuleManagers         : {}
PSComputerName                 :
```

The one that is not:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-DSCLocalConfigurationManager


ActionAfterReboot              : ContinueConfiguration
AllowModuleOverWrite           : False
CertificateID                  :
ConfigurationDownloadManagers  : {}
ConfigurationID                : 814b8ec2-7c1b-2359-8342-4ec23a4e576b
ConfigurationMode              : ApplyAndAutoCorrect
ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins : 15
Credential                     :
DebugMode                      : {NONE}
DownloadManagerCustomData      : {MSFT_KeyValuePair (key = "ServerUrl"), MSFT_KeyValuePair (key =
                                 "AllowUnsecureConnection")}
DownloadManagerName            : WebDownloadManager
LCMCompatibleVersions          : {1.0, 2.0}
LCMState                       : Idle
LCMStateDetail                 :
LCMVersion                     : 2.0
StatusRetentionTimeInDays      : 10
PartialConfigurations          :
RebootNodeIfNeeded             : False
RefreshFrequencyMins           : 30
RefreshMode                    : Pull
ReportManagers                 : {}
ResourceModuleManagers         : {}
PSComputerName                 :
```

Not sure why the second one is running ever 5 hours as it looks to be configured for every 15 min.... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If it is WMF 5.0 RTM, you can check the configuration frequency settings as seen by the timers itself using:

```
get-winevent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-DSC/Operational  | where {$_.Id -eq 4309}
```

This event contains information about the frequency of the timer as seen by the timer that triggers the consistency. 
If the value is not 15 min, perform Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager again on the affected node and check the event again.
If the value is 15 min, look for 2 more events indicating a consistency run( you want the one with flag 1 for consistency check):

```
get-winevent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-DSC/Operational  | where {($_.Id -eq 4343)-or ($_.Id -eq 4312)}
```